# StackOverflow Exception from get and set

Tags: c#, get, set

I have the following code:

```
namespace QuantStrats
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string FilePath = "C:\\Users\\files\\DJ.csv";
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(FilePath);
            string line;
            List<Data> Data = new List<Data>();     

            while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Data Tick = new Data();
                string [] values = line.Split(',');
                Tick.SetFields(values[1], values[2]);
                Data.Add(Tick);
            }

            for (int ii = 0; ii < Data.Count; ii++)
            {
                Data TickDataValues = new Data();
                TickDataValues = Data[ii];             
                Console.Write("TIME :" + TickDataValues.time + " Price : " + TickDataValues.price +  Environment.NewLine);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class Data
    {
        public DateTime time
        {
            get { return this.time; }
            set
            {
                this.time = value;                
            }
        }

        public double price
        {
            get { return this.price; }
            set
            {
                this.price = value;                
            }
        }

        public void SetFields(string dateTimeValue, string PriceValue)
        {
            try
            {
                this.time = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimeValue);
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("DateTimeFailed " + dateTimeValue + Environment.NewLine);
            }

            try
            {
                this.price = Convert.ToDouble(PriceValue);
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("PriceFailed " + PriceValue + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I get a stack overflow exception.

I know it is because I am not doing my get and sets correctly and am entering an infinite loop, but I cannot see why exactly this is happening?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
public DateTime time
{
    get { return this.time; }
    set
    {
        this.time = value;                
    }
}
```

you aren't using backing fields, but setting the property itself from within the property setter.

You can fix this by using 1) an auto property

```
public DateTime Time { get; set; }
```

or 2) a backing field

```
private DateTime _time;
public Datetime Time 
{
    get { return _time; }
    set { _time = value; }
}
```

they both equate to the same code.

For an explanation, when you get `time` in your code:

```
get { return this.time; }
```

it has to retrieve the value of `time` to return.  It does that by calling the `get` on `time`, which has to get retrieve the value of `time`, etc.

Comment: Backing *fields*, not backing properties.

Comment: yep thanks @JonSkeet, trying to be first and typing too quickly

Comment: Definitely a preference for #1 unless you need to do additional validation or other logic when setting/getting a property.

Answer (score 3):

> I cannot see why exactly this is happening?

```
    public double price
    {
        get { return this.price; }
        set
        {
            this.price = value;                
        }
    }
```

When you "get" `price`,  the getter for `price` is called, which calls the getter for `price`, which calls the getter for `price`, which...

Just use auto-implement properties if you don't want to mess with a backing field:

```
    public DateTime Time {get; set;}
    public double Price {get; set;}
```

Some other observations:

1. The standard convention for property names is to start them with a capital letter, which is why I changed your properties to `Time` and `Price` in my examples.
2. You may want to consider using `decimal` for a property like `Price` if you do any floating-point math, since `double` has some slight imprecision when representing decimal numbers like 1.1.  `decimal` will store the number exacly without any loss of precision.
3. Just writing to the console in a `catch` block seems incorrect.  You are basically ignoring the error (from a logic flow sense).  Rather than accepting strings in the class and parsing them, I would do the validation in the *calling* code and making sure the inputs are valid before passing them to the class.

Answer (score 2):

Properties getters and setters are really just `getXXX` and `setXXX` methods (that's how they are compiled). Because you set the property from the property itself, it is if you were recurring endlessly on a method.

```
public DateTime time()
{
    return time();
}
```

As stated by other answers, you can use backing fields or auto-implemented properties.