# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' in application.exe

Tags: c#, sql-server

I get this error when I try to connect to my database. Does anyone know how to fix this error?

[image]

Any type of feedback is appreciated. Thank you

This is in my `DBConnection` Class

```
namespace A.B.BesmonteDentalClinic
{
    class DBConnection
    {
        SqlConnection connection;
        int flag = 0;

        public int Flag
        {
            get { return flag; }
        }

        public SqlConnection Connection
        {
            get { return this.Connection; }
        }

        public DBConnection()
        {
            this.connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-J3KOF5O;Initial Catalog=besmontedental;Integrated Security=True");

            try
            {
                this.connection.Open();
                flag = 1;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                flag = 0;
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code on the Form1 Load

```
var con = new DBConnection();

try
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 id FROM accounts ORDER BY id desc;", con.Connection);
    SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (rd.HasRows)
    {
        rd.Read();
        int id = rd.GetInt32(0) + 1;
        txtID.Text = id.ToString();
    }                
}
```

Comment: Your `Connection` property attempts to access itself to obtain a value, rather than the backing field.

Comment: Note also that this looks suspiciously like you're planning to share `SqlConnection` objects around. That's usually a recipe for issues too.

Comment: This is one of the reasons auto properties were created!

Comment: Somewhat off-topic but `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, and `SqlDataReader` all implement `IDisposable`, so they should all be wrapped in a [`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) statement.

Comment: This is one of those things that should have been immediately obvious when debugging...

Comment: Would be a good idea to remove client names from your code

Comment: one more note. instead of `SELECT TOP 1 id FROM accounts ORDER BY id desc` just call `SELECT max(ID) + 1 as Result FROM accounts`

Comment: @Zam That's not really much better and is still susceptible to race conditions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StackOverflow Exception from get and set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32977482/stackoverflow-exception-from-get-and-set)

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. It seems that this is not the right code when calling a connection from class. Can you suggests what is the right codes for it? Thank you really appreciate it

Comment: This is a very bad way to handle incrementing a number. Let alone a poor way of handling connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to answer your `StackOverflowException` issue. Note that there are other issues in your code that you can address in StackExchange CodeReview. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

The issue here is that your *Connection property is calling itself*. When your consumer calls it, the property will infinitely keep calling itself until it Stack overflows.

Change your class to use .NET's auto properties (no need for a backing field). 
More info on Auto properties, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties

```
class DBConnection
{
    public int Flag { get; private set; }

    public SqlConnection Connection { get; private set; }

    public DBConnection()
    {
        Connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-J3KOF5O;Initial Catalog=besmontedental;Integrated Security=True");

        try
        {
            Connection.Open();
            Flag = 1;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Flag = 0;

            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be a good thing to implement IDisposable on DbConnection since it contains SqlConnection it should be disposed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it seems that this is not the right code when calling a connection from class. Can you suggests what is the right codes for it? Thank you d.moncada!