# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in FreeOnTheBar.exe

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

A `StackOverflowException` is thrown in my program and I don't understand why.
Can someone please explain what is happening?

This screenshot shows where exactly the exception is being thrown:
[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApYMb.png)

#### My code:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = new WhiteWine();
        t.Name = "Tom";
        t.year = 1414;

        string f = t.Prepare;      
    }
}
```

```cs
class WhiteWine : Wine
{
    public override string Prepare
    {
        get
        {
            return $"Well, {this.Name} is a cold wine, therefor it served cold. \n All you need to di is take it out from the refrigerator, pour it into a glass and serve.";
        }
    }

    public override string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return $"{this.Name} ({this.year})";
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
public class Wine : Drink
{
    public int year { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class Drink : Idrink
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        
    public virtual string Prepare { get; }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [StackOverflow Exception from get and set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32977482/stackoverflow-exception-from-get-and-set)

Comment: Can you add your Wine class as well?

Comment: Yes I add but Mario is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `WhiteWine.Name` get accessor produces infinite recursion, because you use `this.Name` to calculate the value of `this.Name`.

```cs
public override string Name
{
    get
    {
        return $"{base.Name} ({this.year})";
    }
}
```

This should fix the issue.

Comment: @arad: if this answer solves your problem, please accept it. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).